# Positioning a text in a file using C program

Tags: c, file, file-io, position

I'd like to write a table to a file using C program in Linux. But I'm unable to arrange it one below the another. Is there anything that can be done? Thanks in advance.

```
fprintf(fp_for_summary,"----------------------------------------\n");
fprintf(fp_for_summary,"| S.No | Filename\t | Complexity Index |\n");
fprintf(fp_for_summary,"----------------------------------------\n");

for(i=0;i<cnt;i++)
{
    fprintf(fp_for_summary,"| %d    | %s\t | %d |\n", i, filename, cmplxty);
}
```

Comment: http://www.eecis.udel.edu/~trnka/CISC105-04F/making_columns.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fprintf(fp_for_summary,"| %6d    | %32s\t | %6d |\n", i, filename, cmplxty);`

Replace the numbers with the correct ones.

Answer (score 0):

You could use fixed widths:

```
int width1 = 3;
int width2 = 3;
int width3 = 3;

fprintf(fp_for_summary,"----------------------------------------\n");
fprintf(fp_for_summary,"| S.No | Filename\t | Complexity Index |\n");
fprintf(fp_for_summary,"----------------------------------------\n");
for(i=0; i<cnt; i++)
   fprintf(fp_for_summary,"| %*d | %*s\t | %*d |\n", width1, i, width2, filename, width3, cmplxty);
```